# Как передать значение textarea из одной формы в другую?

Tags: html, textarea

Доброго времени суток всем!

Сущесвует на одной форме textarea, нужно передать это же значение в другую страницу, где будет форма тоже с textarea.
Загвоска в том, что обе страницы .html , если ставить .php то соответсвенно посыпиться весь шаблон движка. Никак не пойму как это сделать

п.с. с передачей переменной в .php файлы проблем нет. Пробовал в сессии хранить, всё гуд, но шаблон у движка у меня с форматом .tpl.html и не компилирует php

Comment: нашли решение ?

Comment: @АлександрНитченко, Возможно, уже не помню, если честно) Проект старый. Но какой-то костыль там точно был)

Comment: можете поискать? тоже столкнулся с данным вопросом

Comment: @АлександрНитченко если прям на чисто html передать на другую страницу, то никак. Но если у Вас был php шаблонизатор, как у меня, то посмотрите его функционал. Кака технология у Вас используется?

Comment: У меня верстка интегрирована с MODX и как-то надо данные перенести с маленькой таблицы на одной странице в большую на другой